# Erro nas plataformas Android e iOS, na função HttpClient.GetAsync(Uri requestUri) para URL redirecionada

Tags: c#, xamarin, redirecionamento

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Xamarin Forms que basicamente usa por meio do HttpClient a função GetAsync(Uri requestUri):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
var uri = new Uri(http://www.appwebservice.meusite.com.br);
httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

Está url automaticamente redireciona para outra url com ip (algo assim http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:81/AppWebServiceBase/AppService.svc/json/WebServiceUrl ) só que este redirecionamento não é feito pelo app mas sim pelo próprio serviço de hospedagem, digamos que se bater o link http://www.appwebservice.meusite.com.br no browser ele será automaticamente redirecionado para a url http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:81/AppWebServiceBase/AppService.svc/json/WebServiceUrl.

Na plataforma UWP isto funciona corretamente, porém nas plataformas Android e iOS dá erro.

Erro do Android:

```
    --- End of managed Java.Net.MalformedURLException stack trace ---
java.net.MalformedURLException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "81\AppWebServiceBase\AppService.svc\json\WebServiceUrl"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:192)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:139)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.followUpRequest(HttpEngine.java:1009)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:285)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Erro iOS:

```
Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
  at System.Uri.CreateThis (System.String uri, System.Boolean dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) [0x0007b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/UriExt.cs:55 
  at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/URI.cs:408 
  at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler+DataTaskDelegate.DidReceiveResponse (Foundation.NSUrlSession session, Foundation.NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, Foundation.NSUrlResponse response, System.Action`1[T] completionHandler) [0x00106] in /Users/paul/code/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient/src/ModernHttpClient/iOS/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:184 
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at OuvidoriaApp.Services.SaudeWebService+<ServiceCall>d__0.MoveNext () [0x000f1] in C:\Plastic.Workspace\OuvidoriaApp\OuvidoriaApp\OuvidoriaApp\Services\OuvidoriaWebService.cs:44
```

Se eu colocar a url já redirecionada, ou seja, colocar o endereço com IP a aplicação funciona normalmente, o problema parece estar no endereço www...

Obs: Alterei as urls e fiz o tratamento dos erros, coloquei de forma resumida onde o erro se localiza, espero ter sido claro na duvida.

Comment: Estranho as barras no stacktrace estarem invertidas ("\"). Endereços de internet possuem barras normais ("/"). Há posibilidadede ter algum erro no redirecionamento feito no seu host?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza então é realmente estranho, porém dei uma olhada e está correto no host